# format float with stripped trailing zeros and decimal point, switching to scientific notation for large numbers in haskell

Tags: haskell, printf, decimal, normalization

I am looking for a method in Haskell to format a floating point number in exactly the way described in [this (Java) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110764/compact-number-formatting-behavior-in-java-automatically-switch-between-decimal), for optimal compactness. I think this may also be referred to as "normalization".

I will copy the example scenarios from that question here:

`2.80000` -> Should be formatted as `"2.8"`

`765.000000` -> `"765"` (notice how the decimal point is also dropped)

`0.0073943162953` -> `"0.00739432"` (limit digits of precision—to 6 in this case)

`0.0000073943162953` -> `"7.39432E-6"` (switch to scientific notation if the magnitude is small enough—less than `1E-5` in this case)

`7394316295300000` -> `"7.39432E+6"` (switch to scientific notation if the magnitude is large enough—for example, when greater than `1E+10`)

`0.0000073900000000` -> `"7.39E-6"` (strip trailing zeros from significand in scientific notation)

`0.000007299998344` -> `"7.3E-6"` (rounding from the 6-digit precision limit causes this number to have trailing zeros which are stripped)

Is there a built-in library in Haskell that will do this, or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: *"Is there a built-in library in Haskell that will do this, or do I have to roll my own?"* You probably want to edit that. Asking for libraries is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `formatRealFloat` from `GHC.Float` module. I am not sure if there is documentation available for that module on haskell.org, but here is a summary of the module: [http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/advprog/resources/base/GHC.Float.html](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/advprog/resources/base/GHC.Float.html)

You will need to modify it of course to suit your needs, but here is an example:

```
import GHC.Float

formatFloat :: RealFloat a => a -> String
formatFloat v
  | v == 0                          = "0"
  | abs v < 1e-5 || abs v > 1e10    = formatRealFloat FFExponent Nothing v
  | v - fromIntegral (floor v) == 0 = formatRealFloat FFFixed   (Just 0) v
  | otherwise                       = formatRealFloat FFGeneric  Nothing v
```

Naturally, it will only work with ghc compiler.

Comment: Awesome! This should be the best answer.

Comment: For JSON numbers, [`formatScientific`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.7.0/docs/Data-Scientific.html#v:formatScientific) can substitute for `formatRealFloat`